# Run JAR file in PHP and write a file

Tags: java, php, file, jar

I have the following problem in php when excecuting a jar file. I use the following command:

```
exec("java -jar JavaProject4.jar";
```

The JavaProject4.jar creates a txt file in a path given in the java code.

When i run the project in NetBeans the txt file is created. However, when i excecute the jar in php i don't get any errors but i can't get the file.

Here the java code I use to write the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Main a = new Main();
    List<Double> l1 = new ArrayList<Double>();

    l1 = a.compute_features();
    //System.out.println(l1);

    FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("C:/wamp/www/test/out.txt");
    BufferedWriter out1 = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);
    out1.write(l1.toString());
    out1.newLine();
    out1.close();
}
```

Im using a wamp server with php 5.2.4 and the latest java version.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Problem solved, I moved the main java file in NetBeans to the default package and also fixed a wrong path and now everything is working as expected.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right path in `exec()`?

Comment: Yes, read my comment in the answer below. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run it with PHP, how are you doing so? Are you using the PHP CLI (Command Line Interface), or are you running it through an Apache Module (CGI or otherwise)? The reason I ask, is because the problem you are having could have something to do with the user who the script is executing as. If you are using the CLI, you are running as your Windows User, however, if you are running it through Apache, then it is running as whatever user Apache is running as. Therefore, you might need to give the relevant permissions to the Apache user for that directory you are writing to.

Regards,
Ralfe

Comment: I created a simple JAR file to write a txt file through PHP in the same way (using WAMP through an apache module) and there's no problem writing it. So its not about permission to write I guess, but some other problem about the Java code. Is it possible that I am missing some dependant JAR files or maybe something wrong with my main class? How could I check that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify the full path for :
- the java executable
- your jar

Example :

exec("/usr/bin/java -jar /my/java/project/path/JavaProject4.jar");